# Progress bar on Copy Folder VBS

Tags: javascript, css, vbscript, progress-bar, hta

I have the following HTA using VBScript to copy a folder from one source folder to a destination folder. I also have a, so far not working, progress bar made in CSS and JavaScript to show the progress. The script is copying the folder succesfully, but I have not found a way to show the progress.

**I need to find a way to show the actual progress in the progress bar when copying the folder.** I have tried with various methods using the statement `For Each File In Folder` but without luck.

I know there are other methods of showing a progress bar, i.e the Windows progress bar, but I would like to use my own.

The following code samples are in one HTA, but I've dividede the sciprts up for better overview. Hope that helps.

The following code is the acutal copy folder VBScript:

```
<script language="vbscript">
Sub Setup
Dim FSO, NewFile, ThisFile
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FolderDir = FSO.GetFolder("..\")

dim WSHShell, desktop, pathstring, objFSO
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WSHshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
desktop = WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
Destination = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(desktop)

Source = "C:\Test\Source"

FSO.CopyFolder ""&Source&"", ""&Destination&"\", True
End Sub

Sub CloseApp
Self.Close
End Sub

</script>
```

The copy script is triggered by the onClick on an image in the HTA script:

```
<HTA:APPLICATION ApplicationName="UPDATE" CAPTION="NO" SCROLL="NO" INNERBORDER="NO" SINGLEINSTANCE="YES" ICON="../images/icon_64.ico" ShowInTaskbar="YES">

<body onload="progressbar(100,75);">
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width="100%">
<tr>
<td id="top_bar" height="25" width="100%" align="center">INSTALLATION</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<br>
<b>Do you want to install the program?</b><br>
<br>
 <div style="width:150px">
  <div id="slider" align="left">
   <div id="sliderbar" ></div>
   <div id="progress" align="center"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
<br>
<img src="../images/installer.png" onclick="Setup()">&nbsp&nbsp<img src="../images/afslut.png" onclick="CloseApp()">
<br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</script>
</body>
```

Furthermore I have a progress bar, which is made in CSS and JavaScript:

```
<style> 
#slider{
 width:100%;
 height:12px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 overflow:hidden;
 background: #FFF;
}
#sliderbar{
 width:37%;
 height:12px;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 background-color: #66FF33;
}
#progress {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: relative;
 top: -15px;
}
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">
 function progressbar(XX, YY){
  var progress=Math.round((YY*100)/XX);
   document.getElementById("sliderbar").style.width=progress+'%';
   document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML=progress+'%';
   document.title = progress+'% Installed';
}
</script>
```

I really hope that someone here can see an easy way to show use the progress bar. This is my last step in finishing a script, so I would be pleased if someone can help me out.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Try this waitingbar here ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377931/find-specific-folder-in-root-of-main-and-all-drives-attached-vbs?answertab=active#tab-top

and ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327153/how-to-play-all-songs-in-windows-player-in-vbscript?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @Hackoo but thank was not exactly what I was looking for. Actually, all I have to figure out is how to change the numbers in `<body onload="progressbar(100,75);">` where the number 75 is the progress as in 75% out of 100%.